# Piano: Beginner fingering question

Tags: piano, fingering

Getting back to the piano after a thirty year hiatus...

I have a question about the left hand fingering in the first bar here:

[image: Men of Harlech opening bars]

I'm generally at a loss on the best way to go about it. I start with LH 5 on G, 3 on D. Then pivot on D to place 5 on bottom C and 1 on middle C, 2 and 3 play B and A. But it feels clumsy? Am I being stupid? Is this the most sensible way to finger it?

Any tips would be welcome!

Answer (score 4):

The best solution would be to take the C and B (and perhaps also the A) into the right hand.

Fingering:

- E = 3 + C = 2 (that might feel odd at first but it works!)
- B = 1

If you then take the A in the left hand (i.e. as written), it will have the fingering:

- G = 5
- D = 2
- C = 3
- A = 1

Bar 2:

- G = 2
- D = 1
- G = 5

Comment: Yes, contrapuntally, the C-B-A line is part of the voices played in the right hand, plus it fits better in my hand, at least, to take them with the right hand.

Answer (score 2):

A piano has a sustain pedal for a reason, and this is a good example of what it's for.

- Play the Left hand G and D with whatever fingers you are comfortable with.
- Press the sustain pedal at the same time as you play the F# in the right hand. (To be pedantic, press the pedal just *after* you play the F# - you don't want to sustain the right hand top G before the F# as well)
- Let go of the left hand notes, and move your hand to the right place to play the second half of the bar. Release the pedal as you play the next chord. Personally I would probably finger the LH second half of the bar 1/5 2 1, not 1/5 2 3.
- Use the sustain pedal again on the last beat of the bar, so you can let go of the C-A and move your left hand ready to play the second bar.

That means you have to coordinate two hands and a foot, not just two hands - but if you have progressed far enough to be confident about playing the string of 3-note chords in bar 2, it's time to start learning to use the pedal.

Answer (score 0):

I would play the Middle C and the B in the 3rd beat with the right hand rather than the left.

Comment: This is a very good idea and I'd upvote this answer if you went into a little more specificity as to actual fingerings, as that's what the question is seeking!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that suggestion - I would probably play the A on the 4th beat with the right hand as well. But without seeing the rest of the score, we can't really make a judgment call on *why* the editor put those notes on the left hand staff, and if the OP wants to play them with the left hand, that's also OK.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say go with 5 on G, then 4 on D. Then, you can hit the bottom C with 5 followed by 1-2-3 for the C-B-A run.